# How do you invert a section of a four bit wide signal in Verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, verilog, hdl

I'm working on this [lab](https://safari.ethz.ch/digitaltechnik/spring2020/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=lab3_manual.pdf) from the ETH Zurich course on Digital Design.

I'm creating a truth table for signals to lines in a 7-segment number display. The display is controlled by a 4-bit input.

One of the segments has the following assignment:

```
assign g = (~input[2] & ~input[1] & ~input[0]) | ...
```

The `...` implies there are more conditions, but I'm interested in the first one.

I'd rather not write this condition in such a verbose way, but I don't know of a shorter way to do it.

Is there an option to do this using something like `input[2:0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that truth tables (i.e., ROMs) are almost trivial in Verilog — you can copy them more or less verbatim from your worksheet:

```vhdl
  input wire [3:0] s;
  reg [6:0] seven_seg;

  always @* begin
    case (s)
      4'b0000: seven_seg <= 7'b0000001;
      4'b0001: seven_seg <= ...
        .
        .
    endcase
  end
```

There's no need to go through a laborious and error-prone manual reduction process. This allows the synthesis tool to do all of the optimization for the target technology. For example, if your FPGA has 4-input LUTs, this will use exactly 7 of them, which is the same thing you'd end up with using your complicated expressions.

---

You asked about the details of the Verilog `case` statement. I first thought I'd send you to one of the many tutorials that abound on the Internet, but since the first several that I found in a quick search were uniformly awful, I'll just summarize the information here.

The basic form is as follows:

```vhdl
case (s)
  e1: statement1;
  e2: statement2;
  e3: statement3;
  default: statement4; // optional
endcase
```

... where `s` and `e1` through `e4` are expressions involving either constants or signals.

It is exacly equivalent to the sequence, but with a lot less typing:

```vhdl
if (s == e1) statement1;
else if (s == e2) statement2;
else if (s == e3) statement3;
else statement4;
```

Verilog requires that either sequence must appear only within an `initial` or `always` block. Therefore, I put my example inside

```vhdl
always @* begin
  .
  .
end
```

The `@*` trigger expression is a special form that allows us to create combinatorial logic using what are normally sequential statements.

So, overall, my code is testing the 4-bit input `s` for all of its possible values, and assigning all 7 bits of the output simultaneously for each case.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a complete beginner to Verilog, could you explain what you're doing here in a bit more detail please? It looks like you're trying to tell me a much better method for setting up logic, but I haven't seen this style before!

Comment: Okay, so `always` is typically used for sequential statements, but it can be made combinatorial using the `@*` command because that says "do whatever's in the always block regardless of any input."? Why can't `assign` be used in this case? In your opinion is `assign` that useful if always can be used in this way?

Comment: `assign` can't be used because `case` and `if ... else` can only appear in an `always` block. Note that all assignments in an `initial` or `always` block must be to `reg` variables. `assign` is still useful when the assignment is to a `wire` and either does not require the use of conditionals, or has conditions that can be handled by `( ... ? ... : ...)`.

Comment: Does that mean you can connect a register directly to a pin with a constraint file? If so, does that mean that at Verilog's abstraction level with `@*` there's not much difference between a register and a wire?

Comment: Yes, it's a historical(?) quirk in Verilog that `reg` does not necessarily mean "register". A register is created only when an assigment occurs in conjunction with a clock or latch signal. And yes, you can use `reg` ports at the top level of your design (where the pins are), but it's more typical that such ports would be used in a submodule of the design, and the top-level connections would all be made with wires.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a shorter way to do this.  You can use the bitwise NOT operator (`~`) on the 3 bits of the bus (`inp[2:0]`), then use the reduction AND operator (`&`) to AND the inverted bits.  Here is a self-contained example you can run to demonstrate:

```
module tb;
    reg [2:0] inp;
    wire g;

    assign g = &(~inp[2:0]);

    initial begin
        $monitor(inp,,g);
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++) #1 inp = i;
    end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
x x
0 1
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
```

`input` can not be used as a signal name because it is a reserved keyword in Verilog.  My example uses `inp` instead.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.8 *Bitwise operators*.

Comment: Depending on the application, it might be more meaningful to write it as `assign g = (inp[2:0] == 3'b000);` It produces the same logic, but may express the intent in a better way.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! What does the `initial` statement do in your code? And what is `$monitor`?

Comment: @Connor: You're welcome.  It is all explained in the IEEE Std I mentioned; also, you can start on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog)